# Camel Restlet GZIP Charset Encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, gzip, apache-camel, restlet

I'm creating a camel web application exposing a REST endpoint via the camel-restlet component and am having some issues with character encodings of the compressed xml responses.

I have manually set Content-Type and charset to `text/xml` and `UTF-8` respectively; set the Content-Encoding to `gzip` and have used the `<marshal><gzip/></marshal>` pattern as the final component in the camel route in order to return a gzipped payload to the client.

The returned payload from the route results in an invalid gzipped file. I have inspected the payloads using Notepad++ at each stage of the gzip marshal and transfer - seeing my valid XML before- and a valid gzipped file after the `<marshal/>` step but the response that is received by the client appears to have been encoded differently by the restlet component.

The normal `[US]<` initial header is displayed in the valid gzip file in Notepad++, however the `<` has been encoded as `ï¿½` in the response from the restlet, along with different representations of the other printable characters. This is returned both to `curl` and my client with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`- which leads me to suspect that I need to remove/change a default character encoding in the restlet component. Removing the charset header gives me a different, still incorrectly-encoded response, which seems to confirm my suspicions.

If I'm correct in thinking restlet is the component causing the change in encoding of the binary data, which encoding should I set/remove, and if not, what should I be looking for to output valid gzipped payloads via restlet?

Many thanks for taking the time to read,

mids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in the end to opt for a Servlet setup - I could not see in the end, how I could use the restlet to achieve what I wanted.

Setting the headers `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING` to `UTF-8` and `Exchange.SKIP_GZIP_ENCODING` to `false`, and removing my `<marshal><gzip/></marshal>` component left the gzip compression to be dealt with automatically by the default transport settings for the servlet.

Adding the additional `<servlet>...</servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>` to my web.xml file and consuming on `servlet:///exposedEndpoint` enabled me to consume the messages in my client using gzip with no further issues.

-mids